# How can I recycle an enameled cast iron dutch oven?

Tags: recycling, usa, metal

I have an enameled cast iron dutch oven that has become unusable due to how cracked and chipped the enamel is. I need to get rid of it, and I'd hate to throw it away because there are several pounds of perfectly good iron underneath the enamel.

Where, if anywhere, can I recycle this? Will a normal metal recycling company be able to process it with the enamel coating?

Comment: Cast iron scrap has very little value , you can probably donate it to a scrape yard. I can't imagine the enamel could make any difference. Or drill a hole in the bottom and use it as a planter. I have a few aluminum frying pans I use as saucers for plant pots.

Comment: You could potentially get it re-enameled? I've heard of bathtubs being completely redone, not sure if it's possible for dutch ovens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast iron has little metallic value, it's not steel, it's source for making steel. It is literally worth about 2 cents per pound. If you wish to recycle it, wait til you have a couple dozen or few hundred pounds to turn in for money.
A black smith might have use for it, if they make steel product from scratch or do wrought iron work

Answer (score 0):

I would expect any metal scrap dealer would take it. Ar our local landfill all metal goes into a pile. Every couple months they crush it and send it out as scrap. There they sort it somewhat.

A better use is to reuse it. Dog watering dish. Plant. Prop for a play.  Bird bath. Mold for large ice pucks for winter decoration.